# Xamarin.Forms and OpenID: fix response_type parameters

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, openid

On Xamarin.Forms, using the Microsoft.Identity.Client nuGet package, i am trying to run the Oauth2.0 and openID flow. I started from this doc official page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Which states i need this structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Dkn.png)

In the android project i have this piece of code that works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGgRT.png)

Only problem, the query parameter response_type shoul be:
response_type=code+id_token

but the library fixes it to:
response_type=code

Everything else is working properly. Any ideas on how to edit the parameter?

I tried cheating using:

```
.WithExtraQueryParameters(new Dictionary<string, string>(){{ "response_type","code+id_token"} }) // error duplicated url key
```

but raises duplicated key error

Comment: Add the images directly in the post and not as link

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official document about the [Authentication and Authorization in the xamarin forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization).

And the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization#issuing-bearer-tokens-using-identityserver-4) said:

> IdentityServer 4 is an open source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core, which can be used for many authentication and authorization scenarios including issuing security tokens for local ASP.NET Core Identity users.

And you can [Signing-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization#signing-in) by the following code:

```
public string CreateAuthorizationRequest()
{
    // Create URI to authorization endpoint
    var authorizeRequest = new AuthorizeRequest(GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityEndpoint);

    // Dictionary with values for the authorize request
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("client_id", GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientId);
    dic.Add("client_secret", GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientSecret); 
    dic.Add("response_type", "code id_token");
    dic.Add("scope", "openid profile basket orders locations marketing offline_access");
    dic.Add("redirect_uri", GlobalSetting.Instance.Callback);
    dic.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    dic.Add("code_challenge", CreateCodeChallenge());
    dic.Add("code_challenge_method", "S256");

    // Add CSRF token to protect against cross-site request forgery attacks.
    var currentCSRFToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    dic.Add("state", currentCSRFToken);

    var authorizeUri = authorizeRequest.Create(dic); 
    return authorizeUri;
}
```